# Spinner loses content after multiple asynctask

Tags: android, json, android-listview, android-asynctask, spinner

I have problem about asynctask and spinner.I have one spinner ,one listview and 2 buttons.

1. I'm databinding spinner with clicking first button(with a json
   service by asynctask)  Spinner shows the data correctly,no problem
2. After that Im clicking another button for databinding listview
   (with a json service by asynctask).And listview shows the data
   correctly ,no problem
3. But now when I click spinner ,spinner has no   data,it loses data.
   Its only showing the last item i have selected  before I filled up 
   the listview.

I'm using a class for asynctask ,its like this BackgroundTast.java

```
public class BackGroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    List<NameValuePair> postparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    String URL = null;
    String method = null;
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    public BackGroundTask(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {
        this.URL = url;
        this.postparams = params;
        this.method = method;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // Making HTTP request
            // check for request method

            if (method.equals("POST")) {
                // request method is POST
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postparams));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } else if (method == "GET") {
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                /*
                 * String paramString = URLEncodedUtils .format(postparams,
                 * "utf-8"); URL += "?" + paramString;
                 */
                String paramString = "";
                int i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < postparams.size(); i++) { // foreach loop
                    NameValuePair nm = postparams.get(i);
                    if (i == 0)
                        paramString += nm.getValue();
                    else
                        paramString += "/" + nm.getValue();

                }
                if (i > 0)
                    URL += "/" + paramString;
                Log.w("myApp", URL);
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

            // read input stream returned by request into a string using
            // StringBuilder
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "utf-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();

            // create a JSONObject from the json string
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSONObject (this is a class variable and null is returned if
        // something went bad)
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

And I'm using this function to databind spinner

```
private BackGroundTask bgt;
Spinner dropdown1;
Button button_UseSelectedItem;
ArrayList<sobject2> arrayListem = new ArrayList<sobject2>();
public void buildCountryDropDown() {
    // EditText textbx = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    // Building post parameters, key and value pair
    List<NameValuePair> apiParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    apiParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idx", "BL"));
    arrayListem.clear();
    bgt = new BackGroundTask(
            "http://10.200.1.167/json/Service1.svc/GetAllCustomers3",
            "GET", apiParams);
    try {
        JSONObject countryJSON = bgt.execute().get();
        // Getting Array of countries
        JSONArray countries = countryJSON
                .getJSONArray("GetAllCustomers3Result");
        // looping through All countries

        arrayListem.add(new sobject2("seçim yapınız", "-1"));

        for (int i = 0; i < countries.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject c = countries.getJSONObject(i);

            sobject2 yeniDeger = new sobject2(c.optString("ad"),
                    c.optString("id"));

            arrayListem.add(yeniDeger);
        }

        dropdown1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dropdown1);
        ArrayAdapter<sobject2> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<sobject2>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayListem);
        dropdown1.setAdapter(myAdapter);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And I'm filling my listview like this

```
    private BackGroundTask bgt_listview;
ListView listview1;
AlertsAdapter arrayAdapter2;
ArrayList<alertx> arrayListem2 = new ArrayList<alertx>();

public void buildListView(String paramx) {
    // EditText textbx = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    // Building post parameters, key and value pair
    List<NameValuePair> apiParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    apiParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idx", paramx));
    arrayListem.clear();
    bgt_listview = new BackGroundTask(
            "http://10.200.1.167/json/Service2.svc/getOrders", "GET",
            apiParams);

    try {
        JSONObject countryJSON = bgt_listview.execute().get();
        // Getting Array of countries
        JSONArray countries = countryJSON
                .getJSONArray("getOrdersParamResult");
        // looping through All countries

        for (int i = 0; i < countries.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject c = countries.getJSONObject(i);

            alertx yeniDeger = new alertx(c.optString("CustomerID"),
                    c.optString("OrderID"));

            arrayListem2.add(yeniDeger);
        }

        listview1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listem1);
        arrayAdapter2 = new AlertsAdapter(this, R.layout.listitems,
                arrayListem2);
        listview1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);

        /*----------------------------------------------------------------*/

        /**********************************************************************************/

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And these are the buttonevents

```
    public void butonEventt(View view) {
    buildCountryDropDown();
}

public void butonEventtListe(View view) {
    buildListView("BLO");
}
```

First I click butonEventt for spinner and then click butonEventtListe for listview.But spinner lose its content after i click second button.
Any help is appreciated,thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is related to you using events around an async task wrong.

On button click, you clear the list, and tell your async task to load from web resource.

But straight away you continue and use the results to repopulate the list. However, as it is an async task, the main thread does not wait for it to complete. So there is no guarantee that the web resource has been accessed, and the list returned in time.

So you are essentially, clearing the list, then adding nothing back to it.

Code to adding to the list, should be inside your `onPostExecute()` method of your async task. This is where any thing achieved in `doinBackground()` should be passed into the UI Thread.

Read the [android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for a basic example of this.

Comment: I removed my answer as I largely duplicated yours. On reflection though, calling `get()` will block, so (a) i'm not sure this is the real cause of the problem, and (b) there's no point in @slayer35 using an AsyncTask like this, except to evade the NetworkOnMainThreadException ...

Comment: @Stevie Ah right, i did wonder. Never seen `.get()` on an Async before. I assumed it was some method of his. I don't see why you would use an async task and then block the UI thread anyway. :S The only other likely scenario is that the web method is not returning anything, due to connection issues etc.

Comment: yep, `.get` should never have been added to AsyncTask IMHO - too easy to abuse :(. And agree, using AsyncTask then calling a blocking method renders it pointless (but does get around the NetworkOnMainThreadException - quite sneaky!). Your suggestion of `onPostExecute` is definitely the way to go. Possibly the OP's problem is with repeat calls wiping out the static jObj? @slayer35, try moving your buildListView code into your AsyncTask's onPostExecute method, and make jObj method-local.

Comment: thanks for your advices.Im trying to learn android,im so newbie :) so Im sorry  if there is something meaningless about the code.Btw I'm trying to do your advices.